# Make a String define in QT pro File with QMAKE_HOST.version_string

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I want something like:

`DEFINES += makeOs=$$QMAKE_HOST.version_string`

So I can use it in my code. Do you have any Ideas how to realize something like this.
My Problem is, that I need to check which Linux-Distribution my project is built on.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [contains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmake-test-function-reference.html#contains-variablename-value), something like this is possible:

```
contains(QMAKE_HOST.version_string, .*Debian.*){
    DEFINES += DEBIAN=1
}
```